# Authentication in SOAP UI while testing web services

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui

I am using SOAP UI for testing the web services. In the Authentication tab, I have entered the username and password and domain name.

```
Sample:
WSDL URL: http://localhost:8080/soap/helloTest?wsdl

Username:hello
pass:helloworld
domain: http://mysysfullname:8080
```

I have given the correct credentials. I also replaced domain as `http://localhost:8080`.

Even then I am getting invalid credentials only. The username and password are correct and they are not my windows credentials.

Can some one help how to give the credentials.

```
Adding Raw Request
POST http://localhost:8080/soap/helloTest HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 1004
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also depends on the **WSS-PasswordType**

verify that also.

Comment: Thank you for response. Can you raw request also

Comment: what is your service authentication type ?

Comment: The authentication type is NTML

Comment: does [this](http://jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.com/2010/03/testing-ntlm-secured-web-services-using.html) help ?

Comment: soapUI 4.5 and above only support NTLM which version is yours ?

Comment: [here](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/authenticating-soap-requests.html) read `Domain` attribute which might solve your problem. OR try upgrading to 4.5

Comment: Is there plugin available for eclipse with sopUi 4.5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22908/discussion-between-techexchange-and-user-222)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting SOAP-UI to use **Preemptive** Authorisation Type.

As per SOAP-ui documentation:

*Send Authentication headers with each request without first receiving an authentication challenge. This is a potential security hazard but will improve performance since only one request will be required for authenticated endpoints instead of two.*